# Javascript replace .something with a var

Tags: javascript, firebase

I want to replace "Sensor1" with a variable, since I want to change what this command does inside a for loop (the number of sensor):

```
  for(var i=1; i < len; i ++){
    let timestamps = [];
    let values = [];
    var d = cdata[i];
    ts_measures.forEach(ts_measure => {
        //console.log(ts_measure.val().timestamp, ts_measure.val().value);
        timestamps.push(ts_measure.val().time);
        values.push(ts_measure.val().Sensor1);
    });
```

I have already tried this option, but it doesnt seems to work:

```
  for(var i=1; i < len; i ++){
    let timestamps = [];
    let values = [];
    var d = cdata[i];
    ts_measures.forEach(ts_measure => {
        //console.log(ts_measure.val().timestamp, ts_measure.val().value);
        timestamps.push(ts_measure.val().time);
        values.push(ts_measure.val().d);
    });
```

I am triying to replace "Sensor1" in the first fragment of code, with d (a variable) as you can see in the second fragment.

cdata[0] = "Sensor1";
cdata[1] = "Sensor2";

I would really aprecciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access a property of an object with its name as a string using `myObject["myPropertyName"]` syntax.

So in your case, considering `cdata[0] = "Sensor1"; cdata[1] = "Sensor2";` and that you retrieve the string value with your `d` variable... just use `ts_measure.val()[d]` to access property value.

```js
 for(var i=1; i < len; i ++){
    let timestamps = [];
    let values = [];
    var d = cdata[i]; // retrieve "Sensor1" (and following "SensorX" string)
    ts_measures.forEach(ts_measure => {
        //console.log(ts_measure.val().timestamp, ts_measure.val().value);
        timestamps.push(ts_measure.val().time);
        values.push(ts_measure.val()[d]); // using `[d]` to retrieve property value
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, you can access a value of an object either by this method:

```
const obj = {a: 1, b:2};

console.log(obj.a);
```

or by this other one:

```
console.log(obj['a']);
```

**So you can try using bracket notation with string or variable inside**